# Having problem sending trace to jaeger agent

Tags: java, mongodb, jaeger

I am trying to get mongo logs in jaeger. Basically I want my jaeger to show my mongo application errors. What is the best method to do this?

I have tried using the maven repo- opentracing-mongo-driver (version 0.1.4)

and in my code I have configured it using -

```
@Bean
public Tracer jaegerTracer() {
    Tracer tracer = jaegerTracer();

    MongoSpanNameProvider customNameProvider;
    TracingCommandListener listener = new TracingCommandListener.Builder(tracer).build();

            MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(
                    MongoClientSettings.builder()
                            .addCommandListener(listener)                   
                            .build());



    //MongoClient mongoClient = new TracingMongoClient(tracer, "http://localhost:27017");
    //TracingCommandListener listener = new TracingCommandListener.Builder(tracer).build();
    return new Configuration("spring-boot", new Configuration.SamplerConfiguration(ProbabilisticSampler.TYPE, 1),
        new Configuration.ReporterConfiguration())
        .getTracer();
}
```

But I am getting this error-

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.opentracing.noop.NoopSpanBuilderImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract startActive(Z)Lio/opentracing/Scope; of interface io.opentracing.Tracer$SpanBuilder.
at io.opentracing.contrib.web.servlet.filter.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:156) ~[opentracing-web-servlet-filter-0.1.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a mismatch with your OpenTracing libraries. It looks like your Servlet Filter integration (io.opentracing.contrib.web.servlet.filter.TracingFilter) is making use of a method that doesn't exist.